# How to synchronize functions written in different modules?

Tags: node.js

I'm new to Node JS, I want to understand how to synchronize functions written in different modules which are not returning any value.

This's my first attempt to ask anything here. Please forgive me if I made some mistake.

As of now, main.js is working for a small range, but for a large range it times out because individual rows are not being fetched and inserted in sync with each other.

1. I've a main.js which runs a for loop to call a function written in another module, fetchPincode.js
2. The function which is called by main.js extracts the data from a URL using https.get
3. Extracted data is then mass inserted using insertMany, this is done by a function written in insertMany.js

I want insertMany await for https.get and this happens in sync, but I'm not able to do so

**main.js**

```
const fetchPincode = require('./fetchPincode.js')

const start_pincode = 110001
const end_pincode = 110097
for(let i=start_pincode;i<=end_pincode;i++) {
    // console.log('state.js '+i)
    fetchPincode.fetchPincode(i)
}
```

**fetchPincode.js**

```
require('dotenv').config()
const https = require('https')
const insertMany = require('./insertMany.js')
function fetchPincode(pincode) {
    https.get(process.env.PINCODE_URL+pincode,(res)=>{
        let data = ''
        res.on('data',(d)=>{
            data += [d]
            if (JSON.parse(data)[0].PostOffice != null) {
                insertMany.insertMany(JSON.parse(data)[0].PostOffice,pincode)
                // console.log(JSON.parse(data)[0].PostOffice)
            }
        })
    })
}

module.exports = {fetchPincode}
```

**insertMany.js**

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
function insertMany(data,pincode) {
    console.log(data)
    MongoClient.connect(process.env.MO_POSTAL,(error,db)=>{
        if (error) throw error
        // console.log('==========> MongoDB Connected')
        db.db('POSTAL').collection('POSTOFFICE').insertMany(data,(error,res)=>{
            if (error) throw error
            console.log(`For pincode: ${pincode}, ${res.insertedCount} rows inserted`)
            db.close()
        })
    })
}

module.exports = {insertMany}
```

**.env**

```
PINCODE_URL='https://api.postalpincode.in/pincode/'
MO_POSTAL='mongodb+srv://abcd:abcd@cluster0.abcd.mongodb.net/POSTAL?keepAlive=true&socketTimeoutMS=2100000000&connectTimeoutMS=2100000000&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2100000000'
```

Comment: I will help you pointing to a research, so you will understand better how JavaScript works. 1 - many calls have an async fashion so js not wait for finish of them unless you tell him how. Here comes next, 2 - you can instruct js wait for result of some call and pass to next step by usage of async/await or by promises. 3 when You work with a long task into a server Which attends other clients you have plan if blocking is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that all get requests are handled in the correct order, you can use `async` and `await`. I am not sure whether the `https` package can work asynchronous -- it might be easier to use `axios`.

I did not test the code below, so you may need to tweak it a bit.
In your `main.js` add `await` (top level await only works for newer nodejs versions, v15+):

```js
await connectToDb(); // see below
for(let i=start_pincode;i<=end_pincode;i++) {
    await fetchPincode.fetchPincode(i)
}
disconnectFromDb(); // see below
```

Then in your `fetchPincode.js` add `async` and `await` (example here with axios):

```js
require('axios');
...
async function fetchPincode(pincode) {
    const res = await axios.get(process.env.PINCODE_URL+pincode);
    // do your thing with the result
    ...
}
```

There also seems to be a problem in your `insertMany.js`.
You open a connection and then after saving the data you close the connection.
Now if the second `insertMany()` is called before the first `insertMany()` is finished, the first might do `db.close()` while the second is not finished yet.
I don't really have experience with mongoDb, but you might be able to rewrite `insertMany.js` something like this:

```js
async function connectToDb() {
   // code to connect to mongoDb
}
function insertMany(data) {
   // code to insert the data
}
function disconnectFromDb() {
   // code to disconnect from mongoDb
}
module.exports = {connectToDb, insertMany, disconnectFromDb}
```